# удалить каталог c++

Tags: c++

Как удалить каталог в c++?
И какой ключ компилятора указать в codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
fs::path dir = fs::temp_directory_path();
std::uintmax_t n = fs::remove_all(dir / "1");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/734717/9210255

Comment: по той же ссылке
std::filesystem::remove_all("myDirectory"); Не работает. 'std::filesystem' has not been declared|

Comment: а вы сами можете удалить, права на удаление этой папки есть?

Comment: могу. тут с компилятором что то  'std::filesystem' has not been declared

Comment: стандарт [с++17](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Comment: используйте флаг для линковки `-lstdc++fs`, проверил на g++ - работает. `Реализация GNU требует линковки с -lstdc++fs, а реализация LLVM требует линковки с -lc++fs`

Comment: 'filesystem' is not a namespace-name|

Comment: у вас возможно компилятор старенький. или вы неправильно флаги выставляете, можете поборотся за filesystem, либо найти более старые способы.

Comment: Ищите file system library https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: mingw какая версия актуальная? mingw-get-setup.exe(Date: 2017-09-06, Size: 91.00 KB)

Comment: g++-8 на линукс работает. проверьте свою версию запустив команду `gcc --version`

Comment: проверил : 9.2.0

Comment: думаю должно работать. попробуйте так `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra  main.cpp -o main -lstdc++fs` скомпилировать