# Почему не компилирует namespace fs = std::filesystem

Tags: c++

Есть компилятор в составе codeblocks, скачивал отдельно mingw.
'filesystem' is not a namespace-name

при компиляции примера из с++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
fs::path dir = fs::temp_directory_path();
fs::create_directories(dir / 
"abcdef/example");
 std::uintmax_t n = fs::remove_all(dir / 
"abcdef");

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48312460/7485582

Comment: #include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; так тоже не работает

Comment: Убедитесь, что компилятор поддерживает С++17, убедитесь, что при сборке используется С++17.

Comment: как мне убедиться?

Comment: В консоли напишите `g++ --version` и скажите, какую версию выведет.

Comment: 9.2.0  выдает. если вручную компилировать без IDE командой : g++ -o prog.exe prog.cpp то выдает ошибку такую же

Comment: В командной строке добавьте `-std=c++17` и еще раз попробуйте.

Comment: Да! так работает! Спасибо. Надо как то добавить этот флаг в codeblocks?

Comment: Я же вам вчера вроде говорил насчет компиляции https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1226858/281034

Comment: действительно говорили. спасибо. я и сейчас не очень понимаю совет "попробовать так:  g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra  main.cpp -o main -lstdc++fs" . Это часть командной строки видимо.